# Create new virtualhost xampp

Tags: xampp, virtualhost

I want to create a new virtualhost xampp with this but it doesn't work.

I put this in 'C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf' at the end of the file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\microCMS\web"
    ServerName f4gmusique
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\microCMS\web">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Obviously, all the files and folders I use exist.

When I write the server name (f4gmusique/) in the search bar on Google Chrome, it return an error page who said "Can not find the IP address of the server". It return the same when I try to find other page of the server like (f4gmusique/accueil), (f4gmusique/sport),...

I also tried this but it doesn't work either :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\microCMS\web"
    ServerName f4gmusique
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\microCMS\web">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have a localhost who work normally just before the virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

BUT, if I delete the code of the localhost and let just the code of the virtualhost, I can see the virtualhost when I write (localhost) in the search bar.

Thank you in advance for your help.